# jquery to change image src of current row only

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows that all have the same class. When an image is clicked, there's a db call then returning json. I have everything working correctly but when I click the image, ALL in the table change. I would only like the current row image to be affected.

Example Table:

```
<tr class="changerow"> 
<td><a href="" class="hide"><img src="image.png" class="someimage" /></a></td>
<td><a href="" class="hide"><img src="image.png" class="someimage" /></a></td>
<td><a href="" class="hide"><img src="image.png" class="someimage"  /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.hide').live('click',function(){
var row=$(this);
$('.someimage').attr("src","newimage.png");
});
```

So, I know I need to somehow identify the current row and create the variable "row". Not exactly sure how to do this. Was thinking using row.parents('.changerow') or something like that. Help please :) Thanks!

Comment: row.parents('.changerow') should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.hide').live('click',function(e){
   $('.someimage', this).attr("src","newimage.png");

   //Closest row
   var $row = $(this).closest("tr.changerow");
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Close! I used $('.someimage',row) based on my declared variable from my initial example. I didn't see any difference with or w/o the stopPropagation so I took it out. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the image in this `.hide` element (and change it's `src`):

```
$('.hide').live('click',function(){
   $('.someimage', this).attr("src","newimage.png");
});
```

The `row` is:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the first row above the current object:

```
$(this).parents('tr:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
$(this).parents('tr').find('.someimage').attr('src'.'new.png');

Also, could you put the click handler on the img tag and not the anchor tag? That would avoid having to use e.stopPropagation() or "return false" on the tag onclick attribute.